# Swift import got error "Could not build objective-C module 'Twitter'" while including a framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, cs193p

I was taking the iTunesU course CS193P Lecture9.

I got this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0tCx.png) while trying to import the framework.

I've already turn on "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules"
The "Twitter" framework was built successfully and already added in the "SmashTag"'s Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

[navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9WcK.png)

Does any one have some clue for this? Xcode version 8.1 and Swift 3.0

Thank you.

Comment: Have you created bridging header yet?

Comment: @Tj3n, the framework is also in swift so I don't think a bridging header is necessary

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the code to swfit 3 and rebuild the Twitter framework in
the same workspace.

The answer here described how to convert the code.
[Smashtag (Stanford CS193p Twitter client) not loading on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42430904/smashtag-stanford-cs193p-twitter-client-not-loading-on-iphone)