# Smashtag (Stanford CS193p Twitter client) not loading on iPhone

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get my SmashTag app to load on my phone. All the certificates and things are in order (i.e., I've been able to load other apps from Xcode onto the phone) but when I try to load Smashtag I get errors related to the Twitter framework.

I load the app, my iPhone appears to launch the app, and then Xcode gives me this message in the console:

`dyld: Symbol not found: __TWvdvC7Twitter4User10screenNameSS
  Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB50558C-00A2-4C61-B81D-F862C8B25EDA/Smashtag.app/Smashtag
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
 in /var/containers/Bundle/Application/AB50558C-00A2-4C61-B81D-F862C8B25EDA/Smashtag.app/Smashtag`

I've done a bit of SO research and it looks like this is some kind of framework issue. In my Smashtag project, the Linked Frameworks and Libraries section has Twitter.Framework, and it's "required", and in Smashtag's Frameworks folder contains Twitter.xcodeproj, and nothing is red or giving any errors or warnings. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

(I tried removing and readding the framework, didn't help)

Comment: I have watched Standford CS193 on Youtube, the source code may not be update to date, any time I load the code, there is build errors, Xcode is a maybe 2 versions higher since this course,everything in constant flux, the code is Swift 2.3 too probably. I would suggest running on the emulator and not focusing too much on trying to get it running on an iPhone,is your time worth it? Rewrite yourself from scratch if you really want it running on your iPhone

Comment: There are currently many question about this, so I assume this is the current course which teaches Swift 3 and not 2.3, so nothing is really in flux anymore, we have source stability (except for code that should have never compiled). @Jonathan you can always search for the error message, does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24043532/dyld-symbol-not-found-nsurlauthenticationmethodclientcertificate-when-trying) help?

Comment: Yes I searched and it looks like a framework issue but I can't figure out what's actually wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, convert the *Twitter* framework to the *Current Swift Syntax* (*Edit* menu, *Convert* item, you then still have to update the *asPropertyList* dictionary type in *User.swift* from *AnyObject* to *[String: Any]*).

Then, be sure the *Twitter* framework also appears in the **Embedded Binaries** section of the *Smashtag* project (as it does in the **Linked Framework and Libraries** section).